Minimum of functional with boundary conditions over twicely differentiable functions
I found a quiz that I cannot find a way to solve, and wanted to know if anyone of you has any suggestions on how to solve it. The problem is the following: find the minimum of the following functional
$$ 
P(f) = \int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right)^2 + |f(t)| dt
$$
over the set of twice differentiable $f(t)$ functions such that $f(0) = h$. 
In particular, the problem requires finding how the minimum cost depends of the boundary condition, for example
$$\underset{\exists f''(t)\;\forall t}{\underset{f: f(0)=h}{\hbox{min}}}\; P(f) \propto |h|^{1/2}.$$

@Aruralreader better now?

I disagree, if you put that candidate function the cost functional becomes $\frac{\lambda h^2}{2}+\frac{h}{\lambda}$ @whpowell96

Sorry, I missed a factor in my calculation. I think the Euler-Lagrange equation is tractable here. I will write up a solution as an answer later

thanks! @whpowell96

The Euler-Lagrange equation associated to this cost functional takes the form $f''(t) = \operatorname{sgn}f(t)$. Since the sign function is piecewise constant, its solution will be a piecewise quadratic polynomial.
If $r_k$ denote the zeroes of $f(t)$, i.e. $f(r_k) = 0$ $\forall k \in \Bbb{Z}^*$, then the $k^\mathrm{th}$ piece of $f$ is given by $f_k(t) = -a_k(t-r_k)(t-r_{k+1})$ for $r_k \le t \le r_{k+1}$, with $a_k = \operatorname{sgn}f_k \in \{-1,0,1\}$.
As the origin belongs to the interval $[r_{-1},r_1]$, the boundary condition imposes $f(0) = -a_{-1}r_{-1}r_1 = h$, as well as $a_{-1} = \operatorname{sgn}f(0) = \operatorname{sgn}h$.
In the case where you would like a continuously differentiable solution, then you need to impose the condition $f_{k-1}'(r_k) = f_k'(r_k)$ too, which is equivalent to $a_{k-1}(r_k-r_{k-1}) = a_k(r_{k+1}-r_k)$. It is to be noted that a single zero $a_k$ will imply $f \equiv 0$ in that case.

Furthermore, since OP is looking for $C^2$ functions, this immediately implies that $f$ can't change sign and hence there are no solutions to the EL equation and the infimum of the functional is not obtained. I think there is still some more work that can be done to show OP's claim but the EL equation isn't very fruitful
